# fixed-length array with optional items in Typescript interface

Tags: angular, generics, typescript, interface, angular2-formbuilder

Angular introduced Model-driven forms with its FormBuilder class, whose primary method `group` has a signature like this:

```
group(controlsConfig: {
        [key: string]: any;
    }): FormGroup;
```

The `any` is actually an array with the format:

```
[
    initial value of model's property, 
    sync validator(s), 
    async validator(s)
]
```

Where only the first element is required.

I decide I'd like something a little more strongly typed than that, particularly on anything which is associated with a strongly typed Model, so I re-define the function in terms of T:

```
declare interface FormBuilder2 extends FormBuilder {
    group<T>(controlsConfig: {
        [K in keyof T]?: [T[K], ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null, ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null];
    }): FormGroup;
}
```

This also means that all my formControlNames in the HTML (and of course here in the group() call) must match the model's properties, which I prefer.

It seems to work but for one snafu:

```
    this.optionsForm = this.formBuilder2.group<CustomerModel>({
        status:    [this.model.status, [Validators.required], null],
        lastOrder: [this.model.lastOrder, null, null],
        comments:  [this.model.comments, null, null],
    });
```

I *must* provide `null` on the unused array slots.

Is there a way to get Typescript to omit the need for the extraneous `null`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no really type-safe way to do this with tuple types, because of the way tuples can accept extra elements. That is, for example, the tuple type `[A, B, C]` will actually accept additional elements of type `A | B | C` ([see docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)).

However, there is a solution! (See attempt 3 below)

(By the way, you've overlooked that Angular has a difference interface for async validators: `AsyncValidatorFn`.)

**Attempt 1:**

```
[K in keyof T]?: [T[K] | ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null];
```

Hardly better than `any` typing (possibly worse, because it looks misleadingly meaningful).

**Attempt 2:**

```
[K in keyof T]?:
  [T[K]] |
  [T[K], ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]] |
  [T[K], ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null, AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]];
```

Seems better at first glance. But the problem is the Typescript compiler will only throw an error as a last resort. So it will accept this:

```
someStringField: ['hi', 'hello']
```

Because this conforms to `[T[K]]` (as tuples in Typescript are allowed to have extra elements).

**Attempt 3:**

There is a better solution, much to my amazement. I found out about this halfway through writing this answer, while reading [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6229) on the Typescript GitHub repo.

```
[K in keyof T]?: {
  0: T[K];
  1?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[];
  2?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[];
};
```

This is an improvement on the previous attempt in that the first three elements are always type-checked properly. `['hi', 'hello']` gives a compile error, correctly. Additional elements are allowed and can be anything, as per usual structural typing, but that's ok.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Clever!   And yeah I knew extra elements were possible but that's acceptable.  (Also +1 for my AsyncValidatorFn miss.)

Comment: You can also specify the initial value as an object with a `value` property and a boolean `disabled` property. To cover that case using attempt 3, change `0: T[K]` to `0: T[K]|{ value: T[K]; disabled: boolean }`.

Comment: late to the party but one can do simply  `type X = [string, string?, number?]` to have optional typed array members

Comment: Thanks @AndreasHerd, I guess this wasn't a feature in 2017